# Variable not returning. Referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

```
import os.path
import re
import socket
host = ''
port = 6366
s = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind ((host, port))
def request ():
    print ("What file should I write to?")
    file = input ()
    thing = os.path.exists (file)
    if thing == True:
        start = 0
    elif file.endswith ('.txt'):
        stuff = open (file, "w")
        stuff.write ("Requests on what to add to the server. \n")
        stuff.close ()
        start = 0
    else:
        start = 1
    go = "yes"
    list1 = (start, file, go)
    return list1
start = 1
while start == 1:
    list1 = request ()
    (start, file, go) = list1
def loop ():
    print ("Listening for requests.")
    s.listen (1)
    conn, addr = s.accept ()
    print ("Connected to {0}".format(addr))
    while 1:
        want = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not want:
            break
        if want == "shutdown":
            thingy = "no"
        print ("Writing to {0}".format(file))
        x = open (file, "a")
        x.write (want + "\n")
        x.close ()
        print ("Done writing to {0}".format(file))
    x = open (file, "a")
    x.write (format(addr) + "\n")
    x.close ()
    print ("Disconnecting from {0}".format(addr))
    conn.close()
    print ("Disconnected from {0}".format(addr))
    return thingy
while go == "yes":
    go = loop ()
if go == "no":
    print ("Shutting down")
```

This is a server.  Whenever I try and return "thingy" on line 50, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python\Server Requests\Listen.py", line 52, in <module>
    go = loop ()
  File "H:\Python\Server Requests\Listen.py", line 50, in loop
    return thingy
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'thingy' referenced before assignment
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I haven't referenced it outside of that one loop. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Well I think it is not going insisde this conditon `if want == "shutdown": thingy = "no"` in your `loop()` function. You can assign a default value to variable `thingy` that would work I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that error;

```
def loop ():
    print ("Listening for requests.")
    thingy=""
    s.listen (1)
    conn, addr = s.accept ()
    print ("Connected to {0}".format(addr))
```

Just add an empty variable called *thingy* in function. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Declaring an Empty Variable and then assign values if it satisfy condition. Your return statement will work.